# Order and insert a title for similar data in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this:

```
id  | part          | Make  
1   | Stabilizer    | Hyundai   
2   | Track Control | Hyundai  
3   | Axial Joint   | Nissan  
4   | Stabilizer    | Nissan  
5   | Stabilizer    | Peugeot
```

I want to order and put a title for each group of parts that belong to same factory.It's like an ORDER BY with a heading starting each group. I am using PHP. The result would be like below:

```
        Hyundai 
1   | Stabilizer    |  
2   | Track Control |

        Nissan
3   | Axial Joint   |   
4   | Stabilizer    |

       Peugeot
5   | Stabilizer    |
```

Comment: You want that, and *I* want a pony. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I know how to do usual ORDER BY. I do not know how I could insert a title into each group. By the way that's why I'm asking.

Comment: @Ricardo by insert a title do you mean just echo the field name? Also, check my answer below.

Comment: MinimumEntropy, yes, I saw your answer, I wan just to show field name before each list.

Answer (score 0):

Try using an SQL statement like `SELECT id, part FROM tableName ORDER BY FIELD(Make, "Hyundai", "Nissan", "Peugeot");`

Or just for one `SELECT id, part FROM tableName WHERE Make="Hyundai";` to just select one.

Edit:

Try something along the lines of

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, SELECT id, part FROM tableName WHERE Make="Hyundai");
echo "<h1>Hyundai:</h1>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['part'];
}
$result = mysqli_query($conn, SELECT id, part FROM tableName WHERE Make="Nissan");
echo "<h1>Nissan:</h1>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['part'];
}
```

You could echo these within a nicely formatted html table should you like as well.

This is where $conn is an inititalized mysqli

Comment: MinimumEntropy,  in your answer I get the order I want for the manufacturers, but I just want to show the manufacturer's name before each list.

Comment: Why not just `echo 'Hyundai'` etc. before each one. You can put the rest in an html table. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: I thought about splitting query like you said, but I need to use it in TCPDF (PDF generation via PHP library) Thats why I need a lean query result through MySQL. That way it's taking a while, but it's working. Anyway thank you.